# Non parametric estimate of cdf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, cdf

I have a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `Nx1`. I want to get a non-parametric estimate the cdf at each point in `A` and store all the values in a vector `B` of dimension `Nx1`. Which different options do I have?

I have read about `ecdf` and `ksdensity` but it is not clear to me what is the difference, pros and cons. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by non-parametric here, but the formula reads  `cdf(x,mu, sigma) = 0.5*(1 + erf((x-mu)/sigma/sqrt(2)))`. The error function is builtin in Matlab

Comment: @JensMunk _Parametric_ means you don't assume a specifc shape for the distribution. Your expression with `erf` assumes a Gaussian

Comment: @LuisMendo Okay. If you use `randn` or `rand` a uniform distribution is assumed `rand` and then an expression is used to converting output to another distribution, e.g. to the output of `randn`. I guess what you are asking for is basically to sample the values of a generated histogram. This gives you the `cdf`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you can compute the empirical CDF very simply:

```
A = randn(1,1e3); % example Gaussian data
x_cdf = sort(A);
y_cdf = (1:numel(A))/numel(A);
plot(x_cdf, y_cdf) % plot CDF
```

[image]

This works because, by definition, each sample contributes to the (empirical) CDF with an increment of `1/N`. That is, for values smaller than the minimum sample the CDF equals `0`; for values between the minimum sample and the next highest sample it equals `1/N`, etc.

The advantage of this approach is that you know exactly what is being done.

---

If you need to evaluate the empirical CDF at **prescribed *x*-axis values**:

```
A = randn(1,1e3); % example Gaussian data
x_cdf = -5:.1:5;
y_cdf = sum(bsxfun(@le, A(:), x_cdf), 1)/numel(A);
plot(x_cdf, y_cdf) % plot CDF
```

---

If you have **prescribed *y*-axis values**, the corresponding *x*-axis values are by definition the quantiles of the (empirical) distribution:

```
A = randn(1,1e3); % example Gaussian data
y_cdf = 0:.01:1;
x_cdf = quantile(A, y_cdf);
plot(x_cdf, y_cdf) % plot CDF
```

Answer (score -1):

You want ecdf, not ksdensity.

ecdf computes the [empirical distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) of your data set. This converges to the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the underlying population as the sample size increases.

ksdensity computes a [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) from your data. This converges to the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of the underlying population as the sample size increases.

The PDF tells you how likely you are to get values *near* a given value. It wiggles up and down over your domain, going up near more likely values and falling near less likely values. The CDF tells you how likely you are to get values *below* a given value. So it always starts at zero at the left end of your domain and increases monotonically to one at the right end of your domain.

Comment: ksdensity can be used also for cdf.